# C# ignore windows string path only get filename

Tags: c#, winforms

how to copy the same string and ignore the file directory path?

> Like Below:
>
> ```
>   "C:\\Desktop\\Username\\filename\\filename"
>   "D:\\Username\\filename\\filename\\filename"
>   "E:\\Filename\\filename\\filename\\filename"
> ```

The Example:

```
string file = dialog.FileName;
string getfile = file;

if(file.Contains("Dangerous"))  // Check the file Contains these word
{
    string getfilename = file.Substring(3);   //with this only available ignore C:\\ or D:\\
}
```

Output:

> Dangerous_2018_09_10_1.csv

Please share any clue with me, Thanks.

Comment: If you mean "drop all of the directory parts", then [Path.GetFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename) ?

Comment: the output i want Dangerous_2018_09_10_1.csv

Comment: @Victor which means you want the *file name*. Use `Path.GetFileName`. There's no `file import path`, that's the directory path.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes is directory path i update the question, thank you for your remind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated after the comment of @PanagiotisKanavos.
This is probably the best way.

```
var fileName = File.GetFileName(file);
```

It could also be achieved this way, but use above if your only intention is to get the filename.

```
var myFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
var fileName = myFileInfo.Name;
```

Comment: @Victor not really, unless you really need a `FileInfo` object. `Path.GetFileName` works without allocating an extra object

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: agreed, `Path.GetFileName()` is a better and shorter way to do this.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos use path.GetFileName will solve it too, thanks for the sharing.